# readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID

Tags: mongodb

I get the following error - while reading a POJO, I am able to insert / update and delete successfully.

We are using mongodb-driver-reactivestreams (1.9.0)

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: An exception occurred when decoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Decoding into a 'FooBar' failed with the following exception:

Failed to decode 'FooBar'. Decoding '_id' errored with: readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID.

A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.decode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:40) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultArrayCodec.decode(CommandResultArrayCodec.java:52) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:60) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.0.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.LazyCodec.decode(LazyCodec.java:47) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.readValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:101) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.0.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at 

Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Failed to decode 'FooBar'. Decoding '_id' errored with: readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID.
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decodePropertyModel(PojoCodecImpl.java:195) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decodeProperties(PojoCodecImpl.java:173) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decode(PojoCodecImpl.java:127) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decode(PojoCodecImpl.java:131) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.decode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:37) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID.
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:690) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:722) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readString(AbstractBsonReader.java:457) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:39) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:28) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext.decodeWithChildContext(DecoderContext.java:93) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decodePropertyModel(PojoCodecImpl.java:189) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decodeProperties(PojoCodecImpl.java:173) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decode(PojoCodecImpl.java:127) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decode(PojoCodecImpl.java:131) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.decode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:37) ~[bson-3.7.1.jar:?]
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: I got the same problem when my POJO has custom methods getId() and setId(String id)

Comment: @GrigoryK - please check the following thread  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2750  Check  Ross's Comment about CLASS_AND_PROPERTY_CONVENTION

Answer (score 9):

Two changes are required to solve this.

1. add following annotation on the field id:

> ```
> @BsonProperty("_id")
> @BsonId
> ```

2. make the field ObjectId instead of String:

> ```
> ObjectId id;
> ```

Now why this solves the problem.

Because if you see in mongo shell data type for id is something like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5d7780d141962c0628915748”)
```

Here “_id” field is of type ObjectId.

And the error message is:

```
"Decoding '_id' errored with: readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID."
```

While reading, the codec converter tries to convert `_id` into a String, and there is no automatic conversion(ObjectId to String). Hence we get the "Failed to decode ..." error.

So if we change then `DataType` from `String` to `ObjectId` then it is direct mapping and the problem is solved.

In the case of Insert, whatever data we are inserting it just inserts into mongo with the same filed types no conversion required.
In the case of `Update` and `Delete`, it tries to find with the `String` if it does not find then also `"Failed to decode '_id'"` error does not appear.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the annotation `@BsonProperty("id")` to the field "id", and it works!

Comment: Well, which the coorect grails package import for this annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this error because at some point my mongodb database had been populated with documents which had `ObjectId id` attributes:

```
    @BsonProperty("_id")
    private ObjectId id;
```

later, I tried to insert a document with `String id` attribute:

```
    @BsonProperty("_id")
    private String id;
```

Luckly I could just drop my collection and remove old documents with `ObjectId _id` and problem solved.

I can't explain with details the reason for this error, but apparently if the collection already have docs with ObjectId _id attributes and you try to persist other with a different type, in my case, a String _id, you get this error.

Answer (score -1):

Just adding @BsonId annotation to the "id" property of my pojo did the trick for me. Not only the "Failed to decode '_id'" error disappeared, it also maps the "id" property of my pojo to the "_id" field in the bson document and vice versa - so far I had two identifiers "id" and "_id" in my documents.