# Mongodb Java driver, make id a String instead of ObjectId

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to get my mongoDB document's _id to be String instead of ObjectId. I have a model:

```
public class Fruit {
    String name;
    String id;
}
// getter setter constructor
```

Connecting to the db:

```
CodecProvider pojoCodecProvider = PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build();
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(getDefaultCodecRegistry(), fromProviders(pojoCodecProvider));

MongoClient client = MongoClients.create("mongodb:....")
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("myDbName").withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
MongoCollection<Fruit> collection = database.getCollection("Fruits", Fruit.class);

// Inserting a document
Fruit newFruit = new Fruit("Apple");
collection.insertOne(newFruit);
```

When I look at the database now, the document's _id is an ObjectId instead of a String. I expected the _id to be String type when inserting into mongodb.

I have tried this approach [readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888126/readstring-can-only-be-called-when-currentbsontype-is-string-not-when-currentbs)

Where we decorate the `id` attribute with `@BsonProperty("_id")` but still the same result.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? A while ago, I answered on a stackoverflow question and created a `ClientData` class that has an `_id` which is a String. The code can be found here: https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-mongodb-query-example. You could try it out. If you have any questions or if it's not applicable to your situation, let me know.

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code or upload a minimal example? By default `_id` is an `ObjectId`, but it is not a strict requirement. Maybe something simple such as adding an annotation `@Id` on your entity could fix the issue.